# How do underivable rules affect parsing?

Tags: parsing, xtext

When writing an XText grammar for a simple SQL dialect, I found out, that apparently rules that cannot be derived from the start symbol affect parsing.

E.g. given the following (very simplified) extract of my grammar which should be able to parse expressions like `FROM table1;`:

```
Start:
    subquery ';';  

subquery:
    /*select=select_clause */tables=from_clause;

from_clause:
    'FROM' tables;

tables:
    tables+=table (',' tables+=table)*;

table:
    name=table_name (alias=alias)?;

table_name: 
    prefix=qualified_name_prefix? name=qualified_name;

qualified_name_prefix:
    ID'.';

qualified_name :
    =>qualified_name_prefix? ID;

alias returns EString:
    'AS'? alias=ID;

with_clause : 
    'WITH' elements+=with_list_element (',' elements+=with_list_element)*;

with_list_element : 
     name=ID (column_list_clause=column_list_clause)? 'AS' '(' subquery=subquery ')';

column_list_clause : 
    '(' names+=ID+ ')';
```

When trying to parse the string `FROM table1;`, I get the following error:

> 'no viable alternative at input ';'' on EString

If I remove rule `with_clause`, the error is gone and the string is parsed properly. How is this possible even though `with_clause` cannot be derived from `Start`?

Answer (score 1):

the problem is that the predicate (`=>`) covers an ambiguity

maybe you can pull together prefix and name

```
Table_name: 
     name=Qualified_name;

Qualified_name :
   (ID '.' (ID '.')?)? ID;
```

or you try something like

```
Table_name: 
    ((prefix=ID ".")? =>name=Qualified_name);

Qualified_name :
   =>(ID '.' ID) | ID;
```

Comment: The former indeed solves an issue with my grammar. Tanks a lot for that. However, this does not answer the question why the removal of the underivable rule allows the input to be parsed correctly. Do you have an idea why this is the case?

Comment: I think the rules are somehow used somewhere in the parser